# How to store and display styled text in iOS with Swift in a UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview

I'm a beginner to iOS development and I'm learning how to build something along the lines of a note taking app using Swift, and I want to allow the user to bold, underline, and italicize text. Kind of like how it's done in Apple's Notes app. I'm using a UITextView right now, but that only allows for basic text input.

I want to know how these options are displayed to the user and also how to store this text information. Simply storing the user input as a string doesn't work because it has no way to retain the bold, underlined, and italicized portions (or maybe I'm missing something). Does apple have API for something like this? I have looked into NSAttributedString, but I'm not really sure if that works for this case.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

[image: how is this done?]

Comment: Yes you can use NSAttributedString and save it as html or rich text format. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43313833/2303865

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at these possible formats.