# How to send NSAttributedString to server and get back with same attribute

Tags: swift

I have a textView and i want to change the text (B/U) bold and italics. This test will save in php web app and iOS app. 
Problem is:-
When i am changing textview attributed string to html then string becomes with tag as-

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd\">\n<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Style-Type\" content=\"text/css\">\n<title></title>\n<meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Cocoa HTML Writer\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\np.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 22.0px; font: 17.0px \'Times New Roman\'; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}\nspan.s1 {font-family: \'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00px; font-kerning: none}\nspan.s2 {font-family: \'Times New Roman\'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00px; text-decoration: underline ; font-kerning: none}\nspan.s3 {font-family: \'Times New Roman\'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 17.00px; font-kerning: none}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<p class=\"p1\"><span class=\"s1\">This </span><span class=\"s2\">is</span><span class=\"s1\"> pikes</span><span class=\"s3\"> AsD this </span><span class=\"s1\">is</span><span class=\"s3\"> finding </span><span class=\"s2\">error</span></p>\n</body>\n</html>
```

But this string with tags is not supported in php, I need string like

```
<b>This </b> <i>text is italics</i>
```

**This**  *text is italics*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43313833/2303865

Comment: @LeoDabus, Thanks for the answer but according to your url output string is not supporting in server side(web App).